# How can I recreate membership tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I have an old ASP.NET MVC 4 application, but they never used the membership or users. I now need to activate it and after uncommenting it all, I noticed the tables in the DB are gone.

Is there an easy way I can recreate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate the membership tables using aspnet_regsql.exe

[Here's some documentation on that](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs)